# Shorthand for multiple file extensions in.gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

Is there a Bash script-like shorthand for matching multiple different extensions in a `.gitignore` file such as:

```
*.{bak,save,aux,nav,toc}
```

?

The syntax above *definitely* does *not* work.

Comment: Maybe use parens? `*.(bak,save)` --- (Literally a guess, not an answer)

Comment: As far as I know, you must put the `*.bak`, `*.save` etcetera on different lines.

Comment: @Jason How would that be better than having them on different lines? (Genuinely curious.)

Comment: Easier to type.

Comment: @Biffen minimizes git diffs (in gitignores), in a semantic way, which I guess is what most of being a developer is about

Answer (score 24):

The method mentioned in the other answer, `*[.bak, .save, .aux,. nav, .toc]`, **does not work**. Or at least, not as expected. It actually selects much more than just those extensions.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to do this, unless the extensions you want to ignore are all a single character long.

According to [Git's documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore/2.20.0#_pattern_format):

> "`[]`" matches one character in a selected range

As can be seen in the example later on that page:

> ```
> # ignore objects and archives, anywhere in the tree.
> *.[oa]
> ```

This would ignore any `.o` or `.a` files.

So this means that a pattern like `*[.ext, .txt, .bin]` will behave identically to `*[beintx., ]` (which is just the same pattern with duplicate characters removed and sorted) and will ignore any file **ending in** (including extension) any one of those nine characters.

I just tried this out on a Git repository of my own and it does indeed seem to follow this behavior.

Comment: Here is how I ignore the generated `*.png` & `*.svg` from a directory: 
`**/asciidoc/**/*.[ps][nv]g`
This would make `*.pvg`, `*.sng` etc match though, but that's the best I can make.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find answers online, so tried it out myself and this worked (creating a test local repository with SourceTree). This is editing the .gitignore file.

***[.bak, .save, .aux,. nav, .toc]**

spaces or no spaces in between the comma and full stop are ok too.

So in my case I had to do this 
*Ignore all files in this directory, except for dll and dic files:*
Web.Site/Third-party Assemblies/* 
!Third-party Assemblies/**/*[.dll, .dic]

Comment: This didn't work for me. Strangely removed some other files too than asked for.

Comment: to other confused humans (like me): yes, you need to repeat the dot every time. Putting it before doesn't work

Comment: This doesn't work. The git documentation states that "`[]` matches one character in a selected range" (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format). So `*.[oa]` would match all `.o` and `.a` files. Your string will actually match any file who's name (including extension) **ends with** `.`, `b`, `a`, `k`, `(comma)`, `(space)`, `s`, `v`, `e`, `u`, `x`, `n`, `t`, `o`, or `c`